# Как запустить spring сервер из тестов?

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, okhttp

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://localhost:8080/json")
            .build();
    Response responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Есть в тесте такой кусок кода. Работает только, если само приложение было запущено ранее. Как можно сделать его выполняемым без предварительного запуска приложения? А то выдает ошибку `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы ваш клиент подключился к указанному хосту, какой-то сервер должен этот хост слушать. Если вы хотите, заменить реальный сервер в лице своего приложения, то возможно вас интересует некоторая заглушка (mock), которая будет слушать необходимый хост. Поскольку вы используете OkHttp, то возможно вам подойдёт [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).